# How to sort a list of strings converted from nullable datetime

Tags: c#, string, list, datetime, nullable

I have a list of strings that I have created from nullable DateTime objects.
Empty strings represent null entries. So the list can look like

```
{ "23.06.2015", "", "01.07.2014", "" }
```

I want to sort the list by date descending. Empty strings should be at the bottom.

```
.OrderByDescending(o => o.DateString)
```

does wrong ordering. I would love to use

```
.OrderByDescending(o => DateTime.Parse(o.DateString))
```

but it will throw an exception for empty strings.

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it work as expected or does it not?

Comment: hi, will DateTime.Parse not throw an exception for empty strings?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out? :-)

Comment: Why don't you sort the datetime objects *before* converting to strings?

Answer (score 0):

Can you format your dates as `yyyymmdd` rather than `dd.mm.yyyy`? If you can then they will appear in numerical (also date) order when you sort them.

Once sorted, you can convert them back to the original `dd.mm.yyyy` format.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var source = new [] { "23.06.2015", "", "01.07.2014", "" };

Func<string, DateTime?> parse = s =>
{
    DateTime result;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
        s,
        "dd.MM.yyyy",
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal,
        out result))
    {
        return result;
    }
    return null;
};

var query =
    from s in source
    orderby parse(s) descending
    select s;
```

The result I get is:

```
"23.06.2015",
"01.07.2014",
"",
"",
```

Of course, you could also do this:

```
var query = source.OrderByDescending(s => parse(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to sort the input as `Nullable<DateTime>` first and then convert them to `string`?

```
var inputDates = new List<DateTime?>() { new DateTime(2015,6,23), null, new DateTime(2014, 07, 1), null };
var sortedDateStrings = inputDates.OrderByDescending(d => d).Select(d => d.HasValue ? d.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"): string.Empty);
```